# PCB Ground and Power Plane Design Guidelines

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, ground-plane

I am converting a design from through hole components to SMT components.

The schematic is identical, except the maximum allowable current through an onboard relay will be halved from 20A to 10A.

It's a long time since I did a PCB layout and I want to do it right.  Everything is pretty straightforward but I am looking at the grounding and power planes, (on a shared physical plane), and not exactly sure what the rationale was for the shape and size of these planes

Are there any general design guidelines for placing power and ground planes?

e.g. Use thickest metal as feasible for ground plane (reduces resistance and provides improved thermal transfer)

I'm especially interested to know if there are any guidelines relating to current.

Interested to know if anyone knows why the previous design was using hatching? Could it be improved solder-ability or related to heat dissipation?

To put this in context, I worked in the test department of a large multinational years ago.  We had design rules that had to be adhered to, I am looking for a similar set of rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "hatching"? I don't see anything that I'd call hatching in your image.

Comment: I'm referring to the circular holes with yellow outline.  OK, typical hatching is like http://techdocs.altium.com/sites/default/files/wiki_attachments/231612/SamplePolygonHatched.png The holes are vias but unconnected to any signal wires.  I assumed the vias were meant to behave in a fashion similar to hatching as they are unconnected but maybe not?

Comment: What nets are they connected to? They look like they're connected to a plane on the yellow layer, and have antipads on the green layer. Probably they are used to maintain a low impedance connection between the yellow layer and some layer that's not visible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  There is no yellow layer.  The vias are all connected together.  I have pasted only a snippet of the design for illustration purposes.

Comment: @SeanJ  At the moment, we have a soda straw vista of your problem.  A bit more information could help us understand what's going on there.  (1) Could you also post the corresponding snippet of the schematic?  What kinds of components do you have?  (2) Is heat dissipation (through ground plane or otherwise) an issue?  (3) How many layers are visible on the layout snippet which you have posted?  How many layers does the board actually have?  (4) What does the while diagonal line represent?  It is a silk screen for a component?  If so, what kind of component?

Comment: All I could give is a soda straw vista, it's confidential.  I am looking for general design rules.